# A proof using Taylor's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $f : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $f'(x) \geq x$, then $f(x) \leq f(0) + \frac{1}{2}x^2$ for all $x \leq 0$.

I'm wondering whether this statement can be proved using Taylor's Theorem. Since we're given that $f$ is only one times differentiable, we can use, $f(x) = P_{0}(x_0) + R_1(x),$ $x_0 = 0$ and $x \leq 0$. This gives:

> \begin{align}
> f(x) = f(0) + f'(c)x, \quad\quad c \in [x, 0],  
> \end{align}

Using the assumption, we can write:

> \begin{align}
> f(x) & = f(0) + f'(c)x \\
> & \geq f(0) + cx \\
> & \geq f(0) + x^2 \\
> \end{align}

But using this method, I not only miss out on the factor of $2$ but also get the reverse inequality. Any suggestions?

Comment: it is for x negative, so you get $-\int_x^0$ and the reverse inequality.

Comment: Oh, right. I see that now. The remainder term, using the form that I have used above, will be negative and not positive. But I'm still not sure where to get the factor of 2 from.

Comment: a primitive of $t$ is $t^2/2$

Comment: I'm explicitly trying not to use the integral form of the remainder term. I'm trying to use the form given by the expression: $R_n(x) = \frac{f^{n+1}(c)}{(n+1)!}(x - x_0)^{n+1}$

Comment: For $n = 0$, this gives me $R_0(x) = f'(c)x$. Since $n+1$ is odd, the remainder term will be negative, but I'm still not sure how to get the factor of 2 using this approach.

Comment: You'll never get the factor of 2 using this approach because you're throwing out information. With this approach, you're only considering the derivative of the function at the point x, whereas integrating will take into consideration the restriction on the derivatives at all points from 0 to x.

Comment: @user156213 All right, but in Taylor's Theorem, isn't the existence of a point $c$ between $0$ and $x$ sufficient to pin down the remainder term. If so, why must we compare the restriction over all the points in the domain; shouldn't one point be sufficient, as the remainder term is pinned down by evaluating the expression at that one point.

Comment: @JunaidAftab You pinned down the remainder term from the perspective of what you know about the value of the derivative at x. In this case, we can obtain a better estimate by taking into account the derivative at all the points between 0 and x.

Comment: The expression of the remainder in function expansion is more or less precise depending on the formulation you choose. Taylor-Young is the less precise, then this is Taylor-Lagrange and the most precise is Taylor-integral. You can hope for a less precise method to give you the precision of the most precise one, but in general this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

$$f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x f'(t) \text{ d}t$$

Comment: I'm not what, if any, difference would this make. It'd be great if you could elaborate on your answer. You're using the integral form of the remainder term. I'm not sure what difference will this make assuming one makes the same manipulations as I did above.

Comment: Try substituting $f'(t) = t$ into the integral above